# i want to get next record of the table whenever clicking on button in swing form

Tags: java

Hai,

I want to create a JFrame with some TextFields and Buttons .I want to get next record in the table whenever i clicks on a "next button" and also a "previousbutton",clicks on it get the prprevous value from the table.

Comment: Cool. And how can we help you?

Comment: And what have you come up with (code-wise) so far to solve your problem?  Do you know how to create a JFrame and add text fields and buttons to it?  Do you know how to respond to events on your buttons?  What kind of table are you trying to get the information from?

Comment: Jisson, you can find a simple "create a JFrame" self-contained demo here: http://blog.pokercopilot.com/2010/04/java-swing-test-frame.html 

You use this as a basis to give it a try and show us how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code to get you started.

- Set the table's selection model mode to support single row selection.
- When the user clicks next get the currently selected row.  If there is no currently selected row then select record 0.  Otherwise select record at selected row + 1.
- Do the same for when they click previous (apart from accessing selected row - 1).

**Tip**: When retrieving the record from the underlying TableModel be sure to convert the selected row **view** index to the equivalent model index.